# Random forest classification with numeric response?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a dataset in which the response variable is categorical, but represented by by a finite number of numeric classes (i.e., 7000,8900,3100,4000). When running a random forest model in R using the randomForest package - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf, it states that for the response variable, y, "If a factor, classification is assumed, otherwise regression is assumed. If omitted, randomForest will run in unsupervised mode."

In my case, will the response vector be interpreted by R as a factor, or as numeric even though there are a discrete number of classes. If the latter, is there way to force it to interpret the response as categorical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type your data is saved in. A number can be represented as a string, integer, float and so on.
You can set the type to a factor using as.factor(), or make it numeric using as.numeric(). This will define the type, which will determine the behavior of random forest.